# How to send "install" method arguments to the card reader using "process" method?

Tags: java, javacard

I wrote an applet for my java card and I want to send the arguments of `install` method to the CAD. so I defined two **static** variables named *theArray* and *arrayLength* in my applet. And after that I made a copy of the `install` method arguments inside the body of that method. Finally I tried to return this variables to CAD in the `process` method. But in the response of `SELECT` command, the card returns `SW=6F00`.

```
package bArrayAccessibilty;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;

public class BArrayReturner extends Applet {

    public static byte[] theArray;
    public static short arrayLength;

    private BArrayReturner() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {

        new BArrayReturner().register();
        BArrayReturner.arrayLength=(short)bArray.length;
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(bArray, (short)0,BArrayReturner.theArray , (short) 0, BArrayReturner.arrayLength);    


    }

    public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException {
        byte[] buffer=apdu.getBuffer();
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(BArrayReturner.theArray, (short)0,buffer , (short) 0, BArrayReturner.arrayLength); 
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, (short)255);
    }
```

Note that, Initialization of the static fields, doesn't change anything.
I mean, I tried this lines in the class body also  :

```
public static byte[] theArray=null;
public static short arrayLength=0;
```

But nothing changed.

What is wrong in my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install method gets called when you install te applet.
The process method gets called when you (select first and)send a command to an instantiated/installed applet.
This means that the install method will get called first and thus:
your first error is tat you want to write to an uninitialized array(theArray == null)
your second error is the wrong parameters for Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(take care for the offsetParameter handed over by the install method)

Comment: Thank you dear Paul. Does it have any solution?

Comment: initialize the byte array before and read JC specification for Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic()

Comment: I initilized the static field `theArray` with `{(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff, ...}` , and my problem solved. Thank you :) But I don't understand the reason of this. Why we must initialized the byte array? As far as I know, the static fields are initialized with `0x00` automatically in the declaration time.

Comment: the byte array is just a pointer that directs nowhere if you dont initialize the array. You can also initialize with `theArray = new byte[length]`. Declaration only declares an object with a variable name, simpe objects like short might be initialized by default, but byte array pointers are not(because the compiler cant guess your array length for example)

Comment: Is this just for **java card** that I need to initialize my static variables before using them in the methods (And the reason is source constraints.i.e. I must allocate the memory in the time of installing, to prevents errors in runtime)? Or in **java** programs I must do it also?

Comment: state the array length in the declaration any try for yourself!